# Does anybody recognize this Beatles poster?

Tags: the-beatles

[image]

Just bought this from a resale shop and haven't been able to find the image online. The poster is velvet.

Comment: Never seen that before.  It's clearly based on a drawing, Paul almost looks like a Hobbit and Ringo looks like the giant from Jack & the Beanstalk.

Comment: Is there any reason to think it wasn't an original --possibly even a singleton --by an obscure artist?  It's quite common for mass market artists to create original compositions with celebrity subjects.

Comment: Is Ringo or El Che Guevara?